# Google apps json data from code.gs to html dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-apps-script

Im creating a google apps script and im trying to have json data from code.gs to the html files dropdown. I don't really know how this is done by not being so experienced with JS and google's own stuff. Heres the code:

```
function PopulateDropDownList() {

var url = 'url for the api call'

var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'api stuff here, it works i have tested it'}})

var json = res.getContentText()
var txt = JSON.parse(json)

people = txt.data.map(function (a) { 
  return [a.firstName, a.lastName]; 
})

Logger.log(people)
return people
       
    }
```

The question is, how do i get the "people" list to the html dropdown selection? I know its something to do with the script tag but i dont really know how to do it. I have also tried the goolge.script.run.myFunction but i dont know how to progress from there

EDIT:

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="droplist">
      </select>
      <script>
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function(people) {
            var select = document.getElementById("droplist");
            for( var dude of people) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              // option.text = dude.firstName + " " + dude.lastName;
              option.text = dude[0] + " " + dude[1];
              select.add(option);
            }
          }
        ).get_people();
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

code.gs:

```
function getPeople() {
 /*json stuff here*/
    var json = res.getContentText()
    var txt = JSON.parse(json)

    var people = txt.data.map(function (a) { 
      return [a.firstName, a.lastName]
      })
     Logger.log(people)
     return people
}

function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Page").evaluate();
  // return html;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "List");
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('choose person')
      .addItem('search', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answers, i was away for the weekend.

Comment: In `Page.html` you're calling the functions `).get_people();` but in `Code.gs` the function has a name `getPeople()`. Try to fix it.

Comment: I really hope you could see how hard im facepalming right now. It works now perfectly. Thanks so much for your help, you're awesome!

Comment: Actually many of this is quite new thing to me. I'm glad as well that I learned how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in many ways. For example:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

```js
// here is your list of people
var people = [
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" }, 
    { firstName: "Roni", lastName: "from StackOverflow" }
];

function populate_menu(people) {
    for (var dude of people) {
        var newlink = document.createElement("a");
        newlink.textContent = dude.firstName + " " + dude.lastName;
        newlink.href = "#";   // <-- here you can add some function or url
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").appendChild(newlink);
    }
}

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body onload="populate_menu(people)">

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown list</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <!-- here will be autogenerataed list -->
        </div>
    </div>

<body>
```

But I'm not an expert as well.

**Second try**

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("template").evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "List");
}

function get_people() {
  // var people = [
  //   { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" },
  //   { firstName: "Roni", lastName: "from StackOverflow" }
  // ];

  var people = [
    [ "John", "Smith" ],
    [ "Roni", "from StackOverflow"]
  ];

  return people;
}
```

template.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="droplist">
    </select>
    <script>
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function(people) {
            var select = document.getElementById("droplist");
            for( var dude of people) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              // option.text = dude.firstName + " " + dude.lastName;
              option.text = dude[0] + " " + dude[1];
              select.add(option);
            }
          }
        ).get_people();
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

The point is the output of the function `doGet()` goes to `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog()`

Comment: thanks for the comment! I tried this solution with some modifications and i couldnt get it to work

Comment: See my second amateur try )

Comment: Hello, i managed to get some kind of output to the dropdown, but it displays only "Undefined undefined"

Comment: Probably the array `people` doesn't get to your html. Or the array is empty. Or you fail to put the values from the array into list in the html file. It's hard to guess if you don't show your code (gs and html).

Comment: I know that my array comes through to the html, it shows the right amount of values, i have atm 3 persons in the array and the html popup shows 3 times "undefined undefined". I think this is something to do with parsin the data and the map function

Comment: I my snipped I used objects `{firstName, lastName}`. Probably you have arrays `[firstName, lastName]`. I've just changed my code to handle the arrays instead of objects. Try it.

Comment: Hey, yes i have it as an array. I get the data from this function:   

var people = txt.data.map(function (a) { 
    return [a.firstName, a.lastName]
    })
    Logger.log(people)
    return people
And the logger data looks like this: [[name, ], [name, name], [name, name]]
("name" is just a placeholder in here for the real names)
I tried your solution but it didnt work. It displayed nothing, not even the "undefined, undefined"

Comment: It should work with array. My snippet work this way. Show your code and data (no need real names of course). I'm almost sure there is some error or typo.

Comment: I have edited my question. I added all the stuff related to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are generating a dynamic site using `HtmlService`. If that's so, you may use templates to dynamically generate the HTML. Create a new HTML file in your project and use [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) to generate the HTML you'd like.

Here a simple example with a `select` tag:

`Code.gs`

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Template')
  template.people = getPeople()
  return template.evaluate()
}

function getPeople() {
  const url = 'url for the api call'
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'api stuff here, it works i have tested it'}})
  const txt = JSON.parse(res.getContentText())
  
  return txt.data.map(function (a) { 
    return [a.firstName, a.lastName]
  })
}
```

`Template.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select>
      <? for (let person of people) { ?>
        <option><?= person[1] ?>, <?= person[0] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

### References

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML (Google Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename) (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createtemplatefromfilefilename)

Comment: thanks for the comment and reminding about one thing. The html stuff in my project are meant to create a pressable button and popup window in google spreadsheets. This i have managed to get done. The dropdown selector should then go inside the popup

Comment: @Roni Then you should take a look to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp (as Yuri Khristich linked). You just need to modify it a bit: add `<base target="_top">` and loop with the template to generate the `a` elements. If you can't seem to make it work let us know what you tried and what is not behaving as expected.